# Why is "which python" not showing me the local python?

Tags: python, path, local, homebrew

I am using Mac OSX Mavericks and have installed Python3 with

```
brew install python3
```

now I am trying to see which python is used with

```
which python
```

But this does not give me the local python. I have my paths set correctly as you can see below:

```
kristians-air:~ kristian$ which python
/usr/bin/python
kristians-air:~ kristian$ echo $PATH
/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
kristians-air:~ kristian$
```

Python files do exist in /usr/local/bin/ !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may have installed it as `python3`, not `python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
which python3
```

gives me the local path. Thanks to BrenBarn for pointing it out!